Как заставить питон написать числа от 0 до 100 с новой строчки каждое, но с интервалом 0.01?
Мне надо сделать что-то вроде загрузки простенькой игры, а для этого надо сделать что-то вроде этого:
0%
0.01%
0.02%
0.03%
И так до ста, буду очень благодарен за решение

for i in range(10000): print(i/100)

Можно вызвать range следующим образом:
for i in range(0, 10001): #до 10001 НЕвключительно = до 10000 включительно
    print(i/100, '%', sep = '') #делим число на 100, печатаем его, печатаем также %, и делаем разделитель пустым

результат вывода кода:
0.0%
0.01%
0.02%
0.03%
0.04%
...

